# JSONP from Marketo custom code widget

Tags: json, jsonp, marketo

My company is launching a Marketo campaign landing page to promote a microsite/testing tool I have built. I have a basic understanding of Marketo, but that is it.

We want to include some stats on the page using live data from my app, I can easily build an API to get this data, and based on what I have read I can show it in the Marketo landing page using a custom code filed.

I am trying to find proof that the code field can handle JSONP, but I can't seem to, I am hoping someone here could validate that it does.

Essentially I would want to put something like this in the code block:

```
    <script>

        // this is pseudo-code

        function show_stats(json){
                  $("#holder").text("stuff from json")
                }

    $( document ).ready(function() {            
                $.ajax({
                  url: "https://myapp.mycompany.com",
                  dataType: "jsonp",
                  jsonpCallback: "show_stats"
                });
});

      </script>


        <p id="holder"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by code field you mean the [custom HTML element](http://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Adding+Custom+HTML+to+a+Free-form+Landing+Page) in the landing page editor - the docs indicate that you can put any scripts in there. I haven't tried exactly your pseudo-code, but anything I've tried putting in one has rendered as expected.

Also, at the template editor level of a Marketo landing page template, it's just a normal HTML document with some extra classes thrown in, so you can put whatever code you want in there - so I don't see any reason why that wouldn't work.

The only thing that you might run into trouble with JSONP stuff, is possibly cross-domain CORS issues?

Comment: Thanks, yes the cross domain issues is what I am trying to avoid with JSONP - I would build the end point to accept it.